Why does Sympy's diff function return a 4D array as an answer?

import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols

x1,x2,x3 = symbols('x1,x2,x3')
X = sym.Matrix([[x1],[x2],[x3]])
print(X)
A = sym.Matrix([[1,0,1], [0,1,1],[1,1,0]])
print(A)
print(X.T*A*X)
D = sym.diff(X.T*A*X , X)
print(D.shape)
print(D)
print(D[0])
print(D[0][0])
print(D[0][0][0])
print(D[0][0][0][0])


The output of the above is as below:
Matrix([[x1], [x2], [x3]])
Matrix([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]])
Matrix([[x1*(x1 + x3) + x2*(x2 + x3) + x3*(x1 + x2)]])
(3, 1, 1, 1)
[[[[2*x1 + 2*x3]]], [[[2*x2 + 2*x3]]], [[[2*x1 + 2*x2]]]]
[[[2*x1 + 2*x3]]]
[[2*x1 + 2*x3]]
[2*x1 + 2*x3]
2*x1 + 2*x3

So this means D is a 4D array. Can someone please tell why sympy.diff returns a 4D array ? (it should be a 2D array of shape (3,1))
It should be a 2D array of shape (3,1).
So I was expecting an ans:
 [[2*x1 + 2*x3], [2*x2 + 2*x3], [2*x1 + 2*x2]]

Instead I got:
 [[[[2*x1 + 2*x3]]], [[[2*x2 + 2*x3]]], [[[2*x1 + 2*x2]]]]


Please read the tags before using them. [tag:diff] has nothing to do with taking derivatives. (And don't forget to include the language tag.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you check, (X.T*A*X).shape is (1,1) when this should really be a scalar. This is messing up the diff operations. Extracting that single result fixes the issue, i.e.
D = sym.diff((X.T*A*X)[0], X)

